# IgniteDataStreamer with allowOverwrite is slower than putAll?

Tags: java, ignite, gridgain

I've wrote some benchmarks on data upload. I expect `IgniteDataStreamer` be faster (or equal) than `putAll(...)` and it is, but except that case:

- number of server nodes: 5
- cache backups: 1
- write synchronization mode: FULL_SYNC
- data streamer allow overwrite: true
- default rest of data streamer's settings

Results are:

`putAll(...)` speed: 126630 per sec

`data streamer` speed: 30430 per sec

In case of not allowed overwrites OR 0 backups+PRIMARY_SYNC data streamer is faster than put all (about 2 times) as expected.

So it turns, Ignite's performance hint to use data streamer breaks?
What is possible reasons and how to avoid data streamer's slowdown?

Benchmark code snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    pojoMap.put(String.valueOf(i), pojo);
}    
cache.putAll(pojoMap);
```

vs

```
igniteDataStreamer.allowOverwrite(false);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    igniteDataStreamer.addData(String.valueOf(i), pojo);
}
igniteDataStreamer.flush();
```

Gridgain CE 8.7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easily explained. If `allowOverwrite` is `true`, then the data streamer will be sending data via [individual cache.put methods](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/processors/datastreamer/DataStreamerCacheUpdaters.java#L107). This approach is much slower than standard `cache.putAll`. Not sure why the data streamer can't use `putAll` in this scenario at least for atomic caches (individual `cache.puts` makes sense for transactional cache to avoid deadlocks). I will check possible optimizations with the community.

As for `allowOverwrite` equal to `false`, the streamer [reaches out all the nodes](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/processors/datastreamer/DataStreamerImpl.java#L2208) that store primary and backup copies directly and does updates in places. For your cluster, it should result in just 5 network requests (from the app to each node) if all the data fits in 5 batches.

Overall, use `allowOverwrite=false` for the initial data loading. As for `allowOverwrite=true`, the community will see if there is any room for an internal optimization at least for atomic caches.

Comment: Thanks for an answer! Did you mixed up "true" and "false"?

Comment: I guess so! Please also consider feeding data to DataStreamer from multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. The naming is also confusing. I corrected my response.